# bulk import 80 lines of data via API

Tags: smartsheet-api

I have a tool that every x hours creates a y set of lines that I would simply like to add to a column into a specific smartsheet. And then every x hours I would simply like to overwrite these values with the new ones. That can have a different numbers of lines.
As I read the API in order to add or update anything I need to get all the row and columne IDs of the smart sheet in question. 
Isn't there a easy way to formulate a JSON with a set of data and columne name and it just auto adds the rows as needed?

Data example is:

```
21
23
43
23
12
23
43
23
12
34
54
23
```

and then it could be:

```
23 
23
55
4
322
12
3
455
3
AUTO
```

I really find it hard to believe that I need to read so much information into a script to be able to add just row of data. Nothing fancy.

Looking into sticking to just using cURL or Python

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add this data as new rows, this is fairly simple. It's only if you would like to replace existing data in existing rows where you would need to specify the row id.

The python SDK allows you to specify just a single column id, like so:

```
row_a = smartsheet.models.Row()
row_a.cells.append({
    'column_id': 642523719853956
    'value': 'New Status',
    'strict': False
})
```

For more details, please see the [API documentation regarding adding rows](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#add-rows).